# MacBook pro Yosemite - unable to dualboot with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, macbook

I have posted this question on the apple forums too but if anyone has any suggestions of potential fixes - please let me know!

I have followed these steps in order to dual boot my MacBook (OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, 2.9GHz Intel i7) with Linux Ubuntu 14.04:

http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

When the process of burning the Ubuntu 14.04 version (both 32-bit and 64-bit) has completed I get the following error message:

"The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

If I then boot from this disk all that appears on the screen is a blinking cursor. I have burned the disk using Disk Utilities at slowest speed of 2x and other speeds too. I've tried burning both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and used a 32-bit disk that I successfully dual-booted a windows system with the same unsuccessful outcome.

I have burned both 32-bit and 64-bit versions using Disk Utilities and Toast Titanium but I am still experiencing the same error.

Prior to booting from the Ubuntu disk I also partitioned my hard-drive to make room for Ubuntu.

Please help on this issue as I really need to get Ubuntu running on this system.

MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2012), OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: I downloaded the iso files from this site (two two links):


http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Answer (score 0):

Found out that macbook 9,2 is only supported by Ubuntu 12.04. I have now installed this successfully using an external hard drive.